# email scheduling in Android using Service / send email in Background in Android

Tags: android, email, scheduling

In my application I have use  [GmailSender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-app)  activity.
By using that i can send email very well with Activity.

Now I want to send email in Background i.e. at particular time using service.
I tried to make object of that GmailSender class and used its sendMail method to send mail in Service. but however it does not execute.

Please give me solution for schedule the email sending using service.

**EDIT:**

I have tried that `GmailSender` in other program with Activity and it works well but in the program which i am currently working it don't work with service.

The exception i get is :

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
04-20 11:53:36.693: VERBOSE/sendMail method(710):   nested exception is:
04-20 11:53:36.693: VERBOSE/sendMail method(710):     java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
```

and for above error i have tried [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990454/using-javamail-to-connect-to-gmail-smtp-server-ignores-specified-port-and-tries-t) too but its not working with me.

--Thanks 
  RB

Comment: If the code "does not execute", try running the code. If the code gives you errors, consider editing your question with error information.

Comment: @CommonsWare : Thanks for above comment. i have used log to trace exception. please check out Edited post for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably missing the `INTERNET` permission in your manifest.