# Calling Store.connect in my servlet hangs

Tags: java, servlets, imap, jakarta-mail

I am trying to get access my GMail inbox using IMAP and JavaMail in a servlet like this:

```
Session imapSession = this.getSession(true);
System.out.println("getting the store");
Store store = imapSession.getStore("imap");
System.out.println("connecting to the store");
store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "address@gmail.com","password");
System.out.println("getting the Sent folder");
Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
System.out.println("Opening the folder in a READ_WRITE mode");
folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
```

The servlet hangs and does nothing more when calling `store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "address@gmail.com","password");`

Any thoughts??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at these to find out how to connect to Gmail. There seems to be plethora of information available out there on this topic.

[Using Javamail to connect to Gmail smtp server ignores specified port and tries to use 25](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990454/using-javamail-to-connect-to-gmail-smtp-server-ignores-specified-port-and-tries-t)

http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/

Also I'd suggest that you first write a sample program - that can be run outside of your servlet code and container - get that to work and then integrate that with your servlet code. This might make it easier for your to develop and debug.

HTH, K