# Exception while sending mail using Gmail Smtp?

Tags: java, email, gmail

I am trying to send a mail using Gmail smtp server .

```
package com;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class Email {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try 
    {
    String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    final String from = "myuname@gmail.com";
    final String pass = "mypassword";
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
    props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

    String[] to = {"to@gmail.com"}; 

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(from, pass);
            }
          });
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

    InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];

    // To get the array of addresses
    for( int i=0; i < to.length; i++ ) { 
        toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(Message.RecipientType.TO);

    for( int i=0; i < toAddress.length; i++) { 
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
    }
    message.setSubject("sending in a group");
    message.setText("Welcome to JavaMail");
    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect(host, from, pass);
    transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

But i am getting an `exception`

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

How i can remove this error?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: duplicate maybe of this ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990454/using-javamail-to-connect-to-gmail-smtp-server-ignores-specified-port-and-tries

Comment: Can you actually connect to smtp.gmail.com 587?  Try `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587`?  It is possible that a firewall rule might prevent connecting out.

Comment: @beny23 where i can run this command telnet??

Comment: do you have an actual smtp client connected to this server ?

Comment: i have no idea.I am looking at this example from http://viralpatel.net/blogs/sending-emails-in-java-using-gmail-id/

Comment: usually on the command line.  If you get connection refused, then you know there is something preventing the connection and the problem is not necessarily related to your code.

Comment: no. could not open connection. So what should i change?

Comment: @Thinker, your code is working fine in my pc.

Comment: @subodh do we have to do some settings in our gmail account before usign it?

Comment: Nothing I did, I just copy your code and change the username password,and to that's and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was in my email Id.
I created a new one and it is working.

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler option would be to use apache commons mail.

```
import org.apache.commons.mail.*;

Email email = new SimpleEmail();
email.setHostName("smtp.googlemail.com");
email.setSmtpPort(465);
email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("username", "password"));
email.setSSL(true);
try{
email.setFrom("yourID@gmail.com");
email.setSubject("hello");
String s="hi"
email.setMsg(s);
email.addTo(id);
email.send();
```